# select last row only if a where condition is met

Tags: mysql

I have a column for messages and I am trying to figure out how I should display messages in "sent" folder.

I run the following query:

```
 SELECT
    `text`,
    `created`
 FROM
    `messages`
 WHERE
    `status` = 1
 ORDER BY `created` DESC
 LIMIT 1
```

I want to introduce a condition so that result is returned only when the last row with `status = 1` also has `user_from = $user` (If the last row has `user_to = $user`, then nothing should be returned).

What should my query be?

Answer (score 2):

you can use a `subquery`

```
select `text`, `created` from T1
( SELECT
    `text`,
    `created`
 FROM
    `messages`
 WHERE
    `status` = 1
 ORDER BY `created` DESC
 LIMIT 1) T1
where `user_from` = $user and `user_to` != $user
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, do you want to do this:

```
SELECT
    `text`,
    `created`
 FROM
    `messages`
 WHERE
    `status` = 1
    AND `user_from` = $user 
    AND `user_to` != $user
 ORDER BY `created` DESC
 LIMIT 1
```

Of course you need to replace `$user` with your string, or use a prepared statement to insert the variable into the query.

Comment: this would return the latest message that was sent by `$user`.. I need it so that the result is returned only if the last message that was sent, was by `$user` (if the last message was not sent by $user, then nothing should be returned)

Answer (score 0):

Select the latest message with status=1 and then use it as a nested query and check your conditions to output this one row result or not:

```
   select `text`, `created`
    from
    (
        SELECT
            `text`,
            `created`,
             user_from,
             user_to
         FROM
            `messages`
         WHERE
            `status` = 1
         ORDER BY `created` DESC
         LIMIT 1
        ) t
        where (user_from = $user) 
              and (not (user_to = $user))
```